# Are questions about TV or movie policy on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Movies and TV have interesting policies and laws about then.  Swear enough, and it becomes harder to show your movie to people.  And until recently, you couldn't say "shit" on TV (in America).

But can I ask about all of this on this site?  More specifically, are the following on-topic?

- Rules and regulations for TV and movie distribution
- Age rating systems
- Censorship
- FCC (or equivalent) rules
- The distribution process (e.g. how distribution networks actually control what I see)
- Questions about cable companies (e.g. why I can't buy channels individually)

Comment: You are asking alot in just a single meta, anyways we already have  [tag:censorship], [tag:content-rating] and [tag:Distribution] question. But it's better if you present example too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you're asking about quite a broad bunch of question categories. But in general, **yes, questions about rules and regulations for movie or TV distrubtion, content-rating or censorship seem to be pretty much on-topic** here and make for an **important part of the film and TV industry, its workings and a work's reception**. But let's look at some of your examples specifically.

#### Rules and regulations for TV and movie distribution, The distribution process (e.g. how distribution networks actually control what I see)

Seeing how distribution is an important part of a film's or TV-show's production, those questions seems to definitely be on-topic here and he have many interesting questions about this, usually tagged [distribution](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution). Some examples would be:

- [What format do movie theaters now use?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/21754/49)
- [Why is international distribution so tangled even for recent movies released first online?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9064/49)
- [How do the new X-Files reach German free TV so fast?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46330/49)
- [TV Shows with Season Parts 1 & 2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13109/49)

#### Age rating systems, Censorship, FCC (or equivalent) rules

This is also an important aspect of a film's or TV-show's dsitribution and we have tags like [censorship](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship) and [content-rating](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-rating) to cover those. Some examples would be:

- [How does the MPAA decide what rating to give a movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/667/49)
- [How are audio tracks censored on TV?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/16982/49)
- [Are premium channels censored in visuals or in words used?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/50586/49)
- [Has a TV showrunner ever blamed U.S. television content rating standards for compromising his/her creative vision?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/19822/49)

#### Questions about cable companies (e.g. why I can't buy channels individually)

Hmm, that's maybe a little more questionable. If anything, we certainly don't really do personal help-desk-like questions about playing and locating content, or why something isn't on Netflix for example. So if anything, try to not word your questions like that (as your example seems to do).

But asking about the **general workings of the TV channel landscape** and how it developed or why it is structured that way might be very well on-topic. Just keep in mind that those questions are by their very nature likely to be localized to a specific country. This isn't a proplem per-se, but you should at least clearly specify what TV industry you're talking about and not automatically assume everything works the way it does in your home country (or that everyone is from there anyway).